# How to call jQuery click function from dynamically appended elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to call a jquery button click function from an element created by the append function, but it is not working below is my source code

```
 var tr = $('#t_body').append(
                             "<tr>",
                             "<td><input type='checkbox' id='check' value='" + (Order_Result.ORDER_ID) + "'></td>",
                             "<td><button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' value='" + (Order_Result.ORDER_ID) + "' id='btn_ViewItem'><i class='material-icons'>pageview</i></button></td>",
                             "<td><button class='btn btn-outline-danger' value='" + (Order_Result.ORDER_ID) + "' id='btn_Delete' ><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></td>",
```

for the above id **btn_Delete** i have created the function as follow

```
$("#btn_Delete").click(function(event) {
    alert("same");
});
```

but when I click nothing is happening I have checked the console there is no error and even the appended table date with has been created properly.

[image]

what is the problem and why it is not working? please provide me a Solution 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#t_body').append("<tr>",
        "<td><input type='checkbox' id='check' value='" + 23 + "'></td>",
        "<td><button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' value='" + 23 + "' id='btn_ViewItem'><i class='material-icons'>pageview</i></button></td>",
        "<td><button class='btn btn-outline-danger' value='" + 23 + "' id='btn_Delete' ><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></td></tr>");
        
$(document).on("click", "#btn_Delete", function(event) {
    alert("same");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody id="t_body"></tbody>
</table>
```

Use it like

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_Delete", function(event) {
    alert("same");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about jquery event delegation. Basically, elements that were not present when the DOM loaded wont be regarded by jquery so if memory serves what you are looking for is

```
$( "#t_body" ).on( "click", "#btn_Delete", function() {
  // Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all using a id for mulitple dom element not recommended

insert name id as `id="btn_Delete"+(Order_Result.ORDER_ID)`
like `btn_Delete1,btn_delete2...`

```
$("#btn_Delete").click(function(event) {
alert("same");
});
```

will work only for already loaded elements.

bind the click event after elements loaded or

instead of doing .click() binding

while appending itself in html, add this `onclick=deleteFn($(this)) or onclick="deleteFn('(Order_Result.ORDER_ID)')"`

onclick of the delete icon it will call `

```
function deleteFn(element){
var orderid=$(element).val();
..... your logic to delete the order
}
```

or

```
function deleteFn(orderid){
     ..... your logic to delete the order
    }
```

`

respectively.